# How to close and dispose Azure ServiceBusClient and ServiceBusSender singletons asynchronously when using dependency injection, e.g., in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, dependency-injection, azureservicebus, dispose

I want to use Azure Service Bus in .NET 7 applications, such as ASP.NET Core Web API pr Worker Service, which use dependency injection.

The [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-performance-improvements?tabs=net-standard-sdk-2#reusing-factories-and-clients) recommends registering `ServiceBusClient` and `ServiceBusSender` as singletons:

> The Service Bus objects that interact with the service, such as ServiceBusClient, ServiceBusSender, ServiceBusReceiver, and ServiceBusProcessor, should be registered for dependency injection as singletons (or instantiated once and shared).

It [also says](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection-guidelines#disposal-of-services) that dependencies will and must be disposed by the containter via the singleton's `IDisposable.Dispose()`:

> The container is responsible for cleanup of types it creates, and calls Dispose on IDisposable instances. Services resolved from the container should never be disposed by the developer. If a type or factory is registered as a singleton, the container disposes the singleton automatically.

Now, the problem with `ServiceBusClient` and `ServiceBusSender` is that both do NOT implement `IDisposable` but `IAsyncDisposable` instead.
I couldn't find any documentation about whether the dependency injection container will also call (and await) `IAsyncDisposable.DisposeAsync()` automatically when shutting down the application.

Is that the case?

And if not, how else am I supposed to dispose the Azure Service Bus singletons when `Services resolved from the container should never be disposed by the developer`?

Comment: Assuming that you're registering the Service Bus clients via `AddAzureClients`, the registration handles both `IAsyncDisposable` and `IDisposable`.   Regardless of which gets invoked, the registration will ensure that the client is disposed, including when the client implements only one or the other interface.   It is worth noting that there was bug with disposal that was fixed for the next `Microsoft.Extesions.Azure` release (1.6.2, expected early March 2023)

Comment: @JesseSquire Thank you. What's the benefit of using `AddAzureClients` instead of `AddSingleton`? I'm just curious. According to @Peter Bons' answer, `IAsyncDisposable` objects are disposed even when registered via `AddSingleton` or `AddScopedService`. Does `AddAzureClients` provide any additional features?

Comment: `AddAzureClients` chains to a set of DI methods in the SDK itself, helping with some common auth and customization needs and adding support for named clients.    It also provides the "clean-up with either dispose" support that I mentioned.   More information: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/tree/main/sdk/extensions/Microsoft.Extensions.Azure#register-clients

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/implementing-disposeasync)

> With regard to dependency injection, when registering services in an IServiceCollection, the service lifetime is managed implicitly on your behalf. The IServiceProvider and corresponding IHost orchestrate resource cleanup. Specifically, **implementations of** IDisposable and **IAsyncDisposable are properly disposed at the end of their specified lifetime.**

Comment: Thanks, I missed that part. Is the class also disposed properly, even if it only implements `IAsyncDisposable` and not `IDisposible`? The word `and` is irritating me here (depending on how it is meant), because the link also says: `If you implement the IAsyncDisposable interface but not the IDisposable interface, your app can potentially leak resources. If a class implements IAsyncDisposable, but not IDisposable, and a consumer only calls Dispose, your implementation would never call DisposeAsync.`.

Comment: @Joerg That is talking about a consumer not calling the right dispose method. This case the consumer is the dependency injection framework of .Net and that is implemented correctly.